# Why does the storyboard.target not get animated?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I want to animate a stack panel on button click, the `Button` I click does animate while the `StackPanel` doesn't

this is in the button `ControlTemplate`

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=menus}"        
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                From="0" To="1500"
                Duration="0:0:2" />
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

This is in the xaml

```
<StackPanel x:Name="menus" Orientation="Horizontal"
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Margin="160 0 0 120">
        <Button Margin="30" Content="Open Account" Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" />
        <Button Margin="30" Content="Instant Card Printing" Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" />
        <Button Margin="30" Content="Banking Services" Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" />
        <Button Margin="30" Content="Bill Payment" Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" />
        <Button Margin="30" Content="Support" Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I want the stack panel to animate from left to right once the button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what about your code is causing your example to fail.   There is probably something going on in the XAML that you didn't post.  Below is a complete and self-contained example that functions exactly as you described:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Clicky Button" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=menus}"        
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                      From="0" To="500"
                      Duration="0:0:2" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
    <StackPanel x:Name="menus" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="0"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="Open Account" />
        <Button Content="Instant Card Printing" />
        <Button Content="Banking Services" />
        <Button Content="Bill Payment" />
        <Button Content="Support"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

When you click on 'Clicky Button' the `StackPanel` grows to a width of 500 over the course of 2 seconds.

Comment: This worked perfectly, however, i placed the event trigger in the ControlTemplate.Triggers of the button style because i want that animation effect to happen when all buttons with that style is clicked